# Heroku - how access shared-database after upgrading to 'dev' plan

Tags: heroku

My Heroku app had its shared database upgraded automatically to the dev plan. I then wanted to upgrade the dev plan to the $9/month plan. I did this, and thinking that it would just allow me to have more rows I deleted the old free 'dev' addon. Now I think I've deleted the database.

I had no backups so I think my only option is to get the data out of the old shared-database. The instructions to upgrade from shared to dev assume you are already on the shared - but I am not. Is there any way to re-upgrade from the shared-database to a dev one?

Comment: I suggest you contact Heroku Support

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ended up contacting support(at)heroku.com.

They fixed it and admitted the upgrade experience is confusing - so watch out when trying to upgrade your plan ...